# Set a PHP Variable through jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

Hey guys i have a system where when you click one div it loads up one div and the other loads up another but instead of this i'm trying to get it to load up content based off a variable to consolidate things betters

So the main question it, how do i set a PHP through a jQuery function e.g.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.redboothApp').click(function(){
        <SET VARIABLE>
        $('.whiter').fadeIn(250);
    });
});
</script>
```

So then in the PHP it will be something like:-

```
<?php
    if (($appLaunched) == 0) {
    echo "0";
}

 else if (($appLaunched) == 1) {
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance, help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you would need to do an ajax call to that php script and then check the returned data

Comment: You're a little off (actually way off). PHP executes on the server, by the time your javascript event handler is executed on the clientside, it's too late to change the serverside code, it's already been sent. You have to either reload the page or use ajax to access something on the serverside again.

Comment: You almost never need to do what you're asking.  Why don't you tell us what you are trying to accomplish **big picture**, so that we can help you devise a different technique.

Comment: Thank you, i'm not too great at this all, pretty new to it.

Well I just want a specific div to fade in and display a certain iframe depending on what choice the user makes, if that makes sense

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a `PHP` variable with `JavaScript`. `PHP` is parsed and executed on the server and then outputs the data to the browser. Once output to the browser any `JavaScript` is run. It can't then "talk back" to the `PHP` that processed it. That would be like Harry Potter giving advice to J.K. Rowling on how best to progress the story.

The closest you can get to this kind of behaviour is with an `AJAX` call -- using `JavaScript` to determine the data to send to a *different* `PHP` script, potentially with return data which can then be processed by `JavaScript`. However, I don't believe that this is the sort of thing you're looking for.